# Upgrading from 4.5.2 to 4.7.2 breaks System.Reactive usage

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm upgrading a .Net framework 4.5.2 console application to 4.7.2 and getting an issue related to System.Reactive

After setting the version to 4.7.2, i run

```
Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName My.Project
```

When recompiling, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1069  The type name 'ISubject<>' could not be found in the
> namespace 'System.Reactive.Subjects'. This type has been forwarded to
> assembly 'System.Reactive, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' Consider adding a reference to that
> assembly.

Referencing this line of code:

```
private readonly ISubject<bool> _lostConnection = new Subject<bool>();
```

[image]

I already have a reference to `System.Reactive.Interfaces`, but it is v3.1.1. The lowest I can select is 3.0.0.

Does anyone know why the upgrade broke this?

Comment: Looks like some upgraded package is trageting System.Reactive 4.x. What packages do you have installed on your solution?